# Snapshot.val() returns the last attribute of the object

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am using firebase cloud function to detect new creation on my real time database ref ("/Project Request/{pushId}"), i need to get data from this creation and add it to fire Store to send email. But getting snapshot.val(); return object only with the last attribute for some weird reason.

```
exports.sendMail = functions.database.ref('/Project Request/{pushId}').onCreate( (event, context) => {

  const requestId = context.params.pushId;

  const data = event.val();
  console.log("Data:  " + data['etProjectTitle']);
  console.log("Data:  " + data.etProjectTitle);

  admin.firestore().collection('project request mails').add({
    to: 'mymail@gmail.com',
    message: {
      subject: 'Project Request!',
      html: "Project Title:   " + data['etProjectTitle'] + 
            "<br>" + 
            "Project Description:   " + data.project_description +
            "<br>" + 
            "Project Technology:   " + data.project_technology +
            "<br>" + 
            "User Email:   " + data.user_email +
            "<br>" + 
            "User Name:   " + data.user_name, 
    },
  });
});
```

console.log statement print undefined and thats also sent in the mails as well. All the attributes mentioned in the html attribute (i.e data.user_email) do exist in the database but for some reason i only get { user_name: "My User Name" }.
The data is added to the ref("Project Request") from android app.

```
project_request =FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Project Request");

DatabaseReference newPost = project_request.push();
newPost.child("user_name").setValue(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getDisplayName());                   newPost.child("user_email").setValue(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getEmail());
newPost.child("Phone No").setValue(mPhone);
newPost.child("etProjectTitle").setValue(mTitle);
newPost.child("project_description").setValue(mDesc);
newPost.child("project_technology").setValue(mTech);
newPost.child("project_proposal").setValue("N/A");
```

db looks like this.
[image: Project Request in database]

Comment: Can you show the code that writes the new data under `/Project Request`? It's especially helpful if you can reproduce it with hard-coded data, or show us very explicitly what JSON is being added.

Comment: Edited the question above. please take a look. @FrankvanPuffelen

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that each time you call `setValue` is a separate write to the database. The first write under path creates that path, and this triggers your `onCreate` Cloud Function. And thus, by the time the Cloud Function code runs, only the `user_name` is available.

The solution is to perform a single write operation that combines all properties you want to set:

```
DatabaseReference newPost = project_request.push();
Map<String,Object> values = new HashMap<>();
values.put("user_name", mAuth.getCurrentUser().getDisplayName());                   values.put("user_email", mAuth.getCurrentUser().getEmail());
values.put("Phone No", mPhone);
values.put("etProjectTitle", mTitle);
values.put("project_description", mDesc);
values.put("project_technology", mTech);
values.put("project_proposal", "N/A");
newPost.setValue(values);
```

Now, since there's only a single call to `setValue`, all data is written in one go, and your Cloud Function can read all properties.

Comment: makes sense...! i ll update you as soon as possible.. Thanks though.